# How can I get raw Json from a pymongo find() call?

Tags: python, json, pymongo, flask-restful

The goal is to get all documents from a MongoDB collection and send them to a consuming application via an API call (using flask_restful.Api).  The object being sent to the consumer has to be raw JSON. The issue I am having is that with the recommended process for handling the cursor returned by pymongo find() command, I am getting a string instead of raw JSON.  This is the call recommended:

```py
def readAll(self):
  record = dumps(list(self.foo_collection.find()))
  return {"results":record}
```

this is what it returns through the API call:

`{"results" : "[{\"foo\": \"bar\"},{\"foo\": \"car\"}]"}`

The escaped string is unusable by the front end.  What I need to be returned is a raw json object as below:

```
       {"results" : 
         [
           {"foo":"bar"},
           {"foo":"car"}
         ]
       }
```

Comment: Seems like you double encode it by dumping it. Remove the dumps and it should be fine.

Comment: wow...  Thank you @TheFool.  Can't believe it was that simple.